# how to remove a pattern in big string that holds specific value using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i got a big javascript variable that holds around 100 `<li> </li>` sets of data. i want to filter these sets if for example some words found in them(remove that set if a word from array found  in them). These words i set them in array(items=["mango","apple","pen"];)

could any one tell me how this can be done?

example of `<li></li>` sets:

```
<li>
        <img src="./mango.jpg" width="180" height="148"
             alt="mango season" class="png">
        <a href="/mango/"  class="corners">&nbsp;</a>


            <div class="thumbnail_label">ok</div>


      <div class="details">
        <div class="title">
          <a  href=
          "/mango/"> mango</a>
          <span class="season">2</span>
        </div>
        <ul class="subject">
          <li>read</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="sub-info">
          <li class="location">Europe</li>
          <li class="price">2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "found in them"? Found in any part or the string or some specific field between the tags?

Comment: Are those "*li sets*" you're talking about collections of DOM elements, arrays of htmlstrings or something else? Please show us the code that fills the "*big javascript variable*"

Comment: thanks sze and bergi for reply. sza for example if word mango found in first href value then i want to remove that li !

Comment: It also looks like you have list items nested in other list items - Do you want to remove ALL list items that contain your word?  Or just the lowest-level one?

Comment: i have many sets of li in my big html variable. so in example set that posted on the top if the word mango found in first href then that means that i need omit the entire li(big li most outer lie or the lie that is example should be omited since word mago found in it) and move to next li ...

Comment: Where do "apple" and "pen" appear in your example?  How would we know where to find them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to list the methodology / functions I'd use to do this - not going to go into the exact code since I get the sense this is a generic example.

1. Change the string to a set of DOM elements so you can use DOM functions on them - maybe make a `<div id="dom_set" display="none">` and do an innerHTML of your big string
2. Create an array of the list items: `var elementArray = document.getElementById('dom_set').querySelector(li);`, so elementArray[0] is the first li, etc.
3. Iterate over the array: `var testString = elementArray[0].outerHTML;` - note that outerHTML is not 100% cross-browser compatible so you'd need to prototype it (can Google how to prototype outerHTML)
4. Within this iteration, iterate over your array of words to check for, and check them.  So it'd be `if(testString.indexOf(badWordArray[j] > -1))` Note that indexOf doesn't work in IE8 so you need to prototype that too.
5. In your 'if' statement, if the bad word is in there then you can remove the node
6. After cycling through all the nodes, you can convert back to a string by `var cleanString = document.getElementById('dom_set').innerHTML;`

There's obviously a lot of the actual code for you to fill in but this is probably a cleaner approach that's less likely to mess up than trying to do a whole heap of elaborate string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the values you want ("mango", "apple", "pen") are the text children of the "a" element inside of a "div" element with class "title" inside of a "div" element with class "details", and assuming you can use jQuery:

```javascript
function itemsFromHtmlFragment(htmlFragment) {
  var selector = 'div[class=details] div[class=title] a'; 
  return $(selector, htmlFragment).map(function(idx, el) {
    return $(el).text().trim();
  });
}

var bigVariable = '<li> <img ... ';
itemsFromHtmlFragment(bigVariable); // => ["mango"]
```